# checkinf if date is real using php

Tags: php, validation, date

I'm trying to check if a date is real, it must return true, and if not, it must return false.

It does not seemes to work when I write 35-02-2012 (Date format dd-mm-yy) it return true, but I was expecting false, I do not know where I'm wrong.

below is my function

```
function isItRealDate($date) {
    if ($date == '') {
        return false;
    } else {

        $rxDatePattern = '/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/'; //Declare Regex
        $dtArray = preg_match($rxDatePattern, $date); // is format OK?
        if ($dtArray == '0') {
            return false;
        } else {

            $tableau_date = explode('-', $date);
            //Checks for dd-mm-yyyy format.
            $dtMonth = $tableau_date[1];
            $dtDay = $tableau_date[0];
            $dtYear = $tableau_date[2];

            if ($dtMonth < 1 || $dtMonth > 12) {
                return false;
            } elseif ($dtDay < 1 || $dtDay > 31) {
                return false;
            } elseif (($dtMonth == 4 || $dtMonth == 6 || $dtMonth == 9 || $dtMonth == 11) && $dtDay == 31) {
                return false;
            } elseif ($dtMonth == 2) {
                $isleap = ($dtYear % 4 == 0 && ($dtYear % 100 != 0 || $dtYear % 400 == 0));
                if ($dtDay > 29 || ($dtDay == 29 && !$isleap)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Does [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) give you the responses you are expecting? or perhaps [checkdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Comment: PHP `checkdate()`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: @islanddave iirc, `strtotime` translates very smart. so the `0-1-2014` will result in the date `31-12-2013` - even if its a invalid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something that just works, use [`checkdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

Comment: BTW, the code you posted is working correctly on my machine. 35-02-2012 returns `false`.

Comment: I did not know it exists, thanks for that answer it really helped me. I was looking since a long time, and it was easy. May God be upon of you

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ibrahim, use:

```
function isItRealDate($date) {
  if(preg_match("@^(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,4})$@", $date, $match)){
    //regex could match 99-99-9999 - checkdate will take care. 
    return checkdate($match[2], $match[1], $match[3]);
  }
  return false;
}
```

This will work for ANY (valid) date between `1-1-1` and `31-12-9999`